# Do nothing but clear all text in textbox

Tags: c#

```
private void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txttrue.Text == "HAAN SHI")
    {
        txtname.Text = ("HAAN SHI");
        txtposition.Text = ("INTERN");
        txtjobscope.Text= ("LEARN");
    }

    else if (txttrue.Text != "HAAN SHI")
    {
        txtname.Clear();
        txtposition.Clear();
        txtjobscope.Clear();

        MessageBox.Show("THE NAME THAT YOU TYPE IN IS NOT IN THE DATABASE");
    }
   else if (txttrue.Text == "Others")
   {

   }
}
```

Hi guys , newbie here .....  the problem I have now is when I set

```
txttrue.text == "Others"
```

the textbox are clears .... why ?

Comment: term "Others" != "HAAN SHI". ( first else if statement)

Comment: There is a correct answer to this question. So please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this code:

```
else if (txttrue.Text == "Others")
```

you just verify if the text is "Others" , and if is, do nothing.

and your conditions is wrong :

1. `if text == HAAN SHI`
2. `if text != HAAN SHI`
3. is never used, because if `text = Others`, will go to 2nd condition

One possible solution:

```
string textValue = txttrue.Text;

if (textValue == "HAAN SHI") 
     { 
     ... code ... 
     }
else if (textValue == "Others") 
     { 
     ... code ... 
     }
else 
     { 
     ... code ... 
     }
```

Comment: you might as well use `switch-case` instead of multiple `if-else`